# C# UWP Flyout cuts text

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, flyout

On the picture you can see that the text is cut.
The width of the flyout menu is long enough, but why is my text cut?

[image]

```
    <!--Button Optionen Flyout-->
    <Button x:Name="button_optionen_flyout" x:Uid="mainBT_Optionen" Content="Optionen" Height="42" Width="105" FontSize="20" Margin="22,429,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled = "False">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyoutSubItem x:Uid="mainBT_Sprache" Text="Sprache" FontSize="20">
                    <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem x:Name="Sprache_DE" x:Uid="mainBT_Deutsch"  Text="Deutsch" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" IsChecked="True" Click="Deutsch_Click"/>
                    <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem x:Name="Sprache_EN" x:Uid="mainBT_Englisch" Text="Englisch" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" IsChecked="False" Click="English_Click"/>
                </MenuFlyoutSubItem>

                <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Reset STM" x:Uid="mainBT_STM" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="FlyoutResetSTM_Click" Width="150"/>
                <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
                <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem x:Name="Button_Debug" x:Uid="mainBT_Debug" Text="Debug" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" IsChecked="True" Click="Debug_Click"/>
                <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Uid="mainBT_Reboot"   Text="Neustart"   FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="FlyoutReboot_Click" Width="150"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Uid="mainBT_Shutdown" Text="Herunterfahren" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="FlyoutShutdown_Click" Width="150"/>
            </MenuFlyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why do you set `Width` to 150, but it is obviously not enough to display the text.

Comment: I removed the width completely. Now it sets it to the correct width.